# Uploading image file from VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I know this question has been asked a lot of times already but unfortunately none of the answers have helped me. I want to upload an image file to my remote Web server (Apache). In my Excel cell, I have the file path of an image and want to use VBA to upload that file to a remote server.

I can't use any 3rd party tool in conjunction (like WinSCP), because that will make my product not very "portable-friendly". I was fine with Windows FTP, but it doesn't seems to be supporting passive mode and hence I also can't use that.

There are some threads which used IE to upload the file, and some which I believe are uploading via POST request by reading file in binary mode.

I want to replicate something similar to uploading files via HTTP POST on a website.

Comment: You wish to post to an HTML web form?

Comment: Does the site require username/password in order to display the web page?

Comment: Alternatively, can you create a web page on your server with a simple form the purpose of which is to allow file uploads?

Comment: No @excel hero I cant, from excel i am http posting some textual data and i need to associate an image with that textual data. Hence i want to have a workflow where end user can specify path of image file stored on local system in a cell in excel just like we do in html web form and my vba code should upload it to my http server no username and password is required..i am posting it to php page...which will process every thing.

Comment: It doesnt requires any username and password.

Comment: Now that you mention posting to html form. I cant help wondering about a workflow where i send a post request to html page stored on my server.. Using php and js i can try to populate the fields in html form..and some kind of auto submit of form must happen. And it can return the result once upload completes? Does it makes sense?

Comment: Ok I will try it..Meanwhile if you have any other idea, then let me know